# how to save data in two different tables of database using single form in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

my controller here two tables name storeData and 2nd is dataFile.

```
public function storeData(Requests $request){
    $data= new Data;
    $data->name = $request->input('name');
    $data->description = $request->input('description');
    $data->save();

        $datafile= new Datafile;
        $datafile->data_id = $request->input('data_id');
        $datafile->dataname= $request->input('$dataname');
        $datafile->save();
        return back;
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is that data doesn't save in database because I'm creating a single model but i don't know how to add values here.

my model is here
 protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description',
    ];
how to add other table values here??kindly told me??

Comment: $data->other_value = $somevalue;

Comment: $data->other_value = $somevalue;
how to consume it i mean how to write it, i cann't understand,Sorry for that but i am new to study laravel